# Elegant way to display long questions

Tags: discussion

After reviewing some of the new posts I noticed that there is pretty big number of questions that take more than one (or even two) screen heights to be displayed.

Maybe some new and elegant way to display such questions needs to be developed?

Comment: Questions shouldn't usually be so long. This might be an indication that a lot of irrelevant information is being shown. Until you point this out to the OP and they remove the noise, scroll bars do a great job.

Comment: @Lix Depends on the site; sites other than SO often need a lot more context. And anything with images can easily overflow one full screen.

Comment: I can't really think of any way to prevent long questions from being long as such; Text needs to be of a readable size and one's monitor is always only so big. Hiding text is completely unacceptable, so there's really not too much to be done, aside from shrinking images (iOS screenshots for example tend to be posted *way* too large)

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather the Ask Question form use some metric to warn when a question might be too long, but I have no idea what that specific metric might be - something involving number of characters or code-to-text ratio.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use one of two tools, depending on the situation :

1) the question is clearly presented, attractive (images help), and the introduction has actual content (i.e. not just irrelevant apologies) : I use the wheel of my mouse. And I go up and down frequently because I don't read a question in a linear way. So I don't see what other tool could better help me in this case.

2) the question seems boring, confused, displays a lack of effort or a giant wall of code : I use the little cross button in the tab to close the question and I don't think pagination could help.